# $_GET and table.php?ini=ABC

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get a input from user which will then pull data from table and display it .

My code is

```
$ini = $_GET["ini_id"];
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","globalgoals");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
else

{
    $country = array();
    //country
    $sql="";
 //!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM country WHERE metrics="$ini");/*table name*/
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        array_push($country,$row['country']);/*column name*/
    }
    //
```

When I enter the url `http://localhost/xampp/testing/Int/table.php?ini=C2C`

I get the error

```
Notice: Undefined index: ini_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\Testing\Int\table.php on line 2
```

Comment: because it's in `$_GET["ini"];`, look closely at the link. **and you're vulnerable to sql injection**

Comment: You should really look into PDO or MySQLI. Mysql_ functions are deprecated, and your code is very vulnerable to injections!

Comment: Its not going to be live ,Its just a demo for exec's

Comment: @Elias maybe you should look more closely, he is using mysqli...

Comment: @MarkoD Goodmorning! :) Didn't notice - but he should still use bound parameters in MySQLi to prevent injections!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In here your trying to get like this `$_GET['ini'];`

```
http://localhost/xampp/testing/Int/table.php?ini=C2C
```

If your trying to get it like `$_GET['ini_id']`

```
http://localhost/xampp/testing/Int/table.php?ini_id=C2C //change here
```

Answer (score 3):

Get `$ini = $_GET["ini"];` because you did not passed `ini_id`.

**Second**

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM country WHERE metrics='".$ini."'");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use isset...

```
$ini = (isset($_GET['ini_id'])) ? $_GET['ini_id'] : null;
```

But perhaps more importantly, you need to secure that variable before you use it as part of a database query. Since your id is alphanumeric use mysqli_real_escape_string():

```
$ini = (isset($_GET['ini_id']) ? $_GET['ini_id'] : null;
$ini = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $ini);
```

Answer (score 0):

one more thing,

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM country WHERE metrics='".$ini."'");
```

You missed the dot before and after the variable.